# Multiple environments in ionic project with Android app

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, environment-variables, capacitor

What´s the best workflow to deal with to environments (DEV and PROD) in one ionic project with an Android app regarding the google-services.json which needs to be in filesystem in folder /android/app.

For firebase environments there is a great way with firebase use... but what´s the best way for google-services.json. I´v two different files, one for firebase DEV and one for firebase PROD`enter code here`

Comment: having the exact same issue. I've been trying with System.getenv("myEnvVarName") but it just returns null ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Have you found a solution?

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but do you have the best way to handle this? Thank you very much